# Magento 2 Out of Stock notification to admin and CC to another email

Tags: magento2, admin, email, out-of-stock

I am trying to see if Magento 2.3.4 has ability to notify an email other than the admin. We have a reseller who has all our products on their website and they need to be notified when a product of ours is out of stock. Is there a way to have the out of stock notification go to a separate email address?

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Comment: We are using Magento 2.3.4